# TuxOnIce won't resume

Tags: hibernate, tuxonice

I'm trying to setup hibernate on my new rig, and I've gotten tuxonice working a few times, but then I had a failed hibernate, and sense then, I can't resume from a hibernate. TuxOnIce has the loading bar, and the text interface, and successfully brings the computer *into* hibernate. However when resuming from hibernate, the screen stays black, then displays random pixels everywhere, and hangs. I'm running it from command line with `sudo pm-hibernate`. I've tried setting `resume=/dev/sda3` in `/etc/default/grub` followed by `sudo update-grub`, but it didn't make a difference.

What am I doing wrong, or how can I successfully hibernate with a near 100% success rate?

**UPDATE 1**

I just looked at `/etc/log/pm-suspend.log` and here are the last two lines of the log file:

`/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm thaw hibernate: success.`

`Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/9`

From my limited knowledge, it looks to me like some sort of hand error in `sleep.d`. Is this the cause, and if so, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest trying uswsusp instead. It can display the status while going into hibernate too and doesn't install a separate kernel image.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with your graphics driver. Is the regular hibernate working for you? What card and driver are you using? If you use proprietary drivers, try the open source ones. I had those glitches with Nvidia on my old laptop, but it properly resumed with the standard kernel. I have been successfully using TuxOnIce a few years ago, but wouldn't want to install a separate kernel image any longer.

By the way, you should specify resume via UUID in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and call `update-initramfs -u` and `update-grub` afterwards.

Comment: I'm using the AMD Catalyst, and I'll try adding the UUID...

Comment: The UUID is already listed in the file.

Comment: I added NOMODESET to /etc/default/grub and I think it fixed my problem, I need to do more testing later...